# Mvvm Cross Logging Setup Class

Tags: mvvm, mvvmcross

I've been following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8E000zu8UhQ&t=2713s) that uses MvvmCross v7, and I'm using v8, so I was led by a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67965424/mvxwpfsetupapp-must-be-a-non-abstract-type-with-a-public-parameterless-const) to the official help topic on *Upgrade from 7 to 8*. Here I am told to create my own Setup class:

```
public class Setup : MvxWpfSetup<App>
{
    protected override ILoggerProvider CreateLogProvider()
    {
        return new SerilogLoggerProvider();
    }

    protected override ILoggerFactory CreateLogFactory()
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().MinimumLevel.Debug().CreateLogger();
        return new SerilogLoggerFactory();
    }
}
```

In the help the generic base class is `MvxAndroidSetup<App>`, but when I change it to `MvxWpfSetup` the compiler tells me:

```
The non-generic type 'MvxWpfSetup' cannot be used with type arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

the log is well documented in the [mvvmcross docs](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/logging-new).
But you have some config problems. I think you miss the [MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf/) nuget.

the MvxWpfSetup (in the wpf-project);

```cs
public class MvxWpfSetup: MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Core.MvxWpfSetup<MvxApp>
    {

        protected override ILoggerFactory CreateLogFactory()
        {
            // serilog configuration
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .WriteTo.File(Constants.LogPath)
                .CreateLogger();

            return new SerilogLoggerFactory();
        }

        protected override ILoggerProvider CreateLogProvider()
        {
            return new SerilogLoggerProvider();
        }
    }
```

dont forget to register all. app.xaml.cs (in the wpf-project);

```cs
public partial class App : MvxApplication
    {
        protected override void RegisterSetup()
        {
            base.RegisterSetup();
            this.RegisterSetupType<MvxWpfSetup<MvxApp>>();
        }
    }
```